# The datetime columns in all the tables on SQL server have shifted by a few hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sqoop, dst

I've created a few tables all of which had a column of datatype datetime. Recently, I think after the daylight savings adjustment, for some reason all the dates have shifted by a few hours i.e. **'2022-01-01 00:00:00' has changed to '2021-12-31 18:00:00'**.

My guess is that it has something to do with the daylight savings and some server setting related to that but I can't figure out how to revert it back.

Edit:
As suggested in the comments, it might have something to do with the sqoop-export i.e. what I'm using to transfer data from hdfs to sql server. So, the question really is how could I look at what is being inserted into the table. Is there a way I can redirect all insert statements to a log file before being sent over to sql server?

Comment: There is nothing that will automatically change the data in your tables. Are you sure the actual data changed and not whatever front end you are using to look it? I know that EF Core will do that kind of nonsense. I suspect there are other automated query tools that do the same thing.

Comment: The timezone on the server changed.

Comment: Without seeing any relevant code we cannot help. Presumably *something* is taking the time and adjusting for UTC, which in the case of the wrong time zone is going to be messy (note that you probably *should* use UTC)

Comment: @Charlieface  I'm connecting to sql server using tableau and see these updated values there. also same thing when I use R odbc library to get the data from these tables.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn presumably, but how can I change it back to what it was before?

Comment: Then it was changed when inserting them. You need to check the code that inserts the data

Comment: @Charlieface, I'm using sqoop export to transfer data from hdfs to MS sql server. However, in that case it should have only impacted the tables created recently and not the ones that were created in the past, the datetime has shifted in all the tables regardless of whether they were modified or not

Comment: Other databases have `timestamp` columns that can behave that way, because there's a concept of a session time zone.  SQL Server does not have that concept.  There is literally nothing that is part of SQL Server that will mutate the presentation of a `datetime`, `datetime2`, or `datetimeoffset` field for time zone offset or DST. You can eliminate that possibility from your investigation. Look at any other components you may be using.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint I think it might be something to do with what sqoop-export is inserting into the table. I've edited the question. Do you know how can I view what sqoop  (insert statements) is inserting into the table?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that tool.

Comment: @ShubhamChauhan Use extended events or profiler?